# Как добавить поддежрку Ts в Next JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Всем привет, хочу добавить в рабочий проект на Next JS (версия 11.1.3) ts/tsx файлов, чтоб последующаяя разроботка ввелась на TS. Проект очень большой. Узнавал еще что можно просто создать новый проект на ts и пернести все файлы со старого,но у меня не получилось пишет ошибку типов, хотя я их поставил.
Попытался в нынешнйи проект добавить файл tsconfig.json ошиьбка такая же. Есть ли  вариант  просто добавить tsconfig.json с определенными настройками? [image: Ошибка]

Comment: ты выполнил команду указанную на скриншоте?

Comment: Да выполянл и через npm, все равно не видит

Comment: попробуйте вот эту команду `npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: @Randall попробывал, все такая же ошибка

Comment: Все решил, проблема была в разных версиях react и types/react